# SMS integration in Website

Tags: java, jsp, sms, liferay, sms-gateway

I want SMS integration in my website, for example, User wants to subscribe through his mobile number,then I want to send the confirmation code to user's mobile,and then if user is confirm I want to add that user in bulk sending SMS list. How to do this please show me the steps in java??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please keep in mind that questions on StackOverflow need to show some amount of effort from the asker -- the questions should show what you've already tried, research you've already done, and ideally, some code. Questions which simply ask for code are generally ill-received. You can edit your question by clicking on the button in the lower-left of your question to include additional information.

Comment: http://www.twilio.com/

Comment: You can use clickatell API please refer to below links. http://smsj.sourceforge.net/examples.html https://www.clickatell.com/apis-scripts/scripts/java/ you to register on clickatell website and you are good to go.

Comment: If you get the phone number and know the cell phone provider, then you can send them an email and it'll get translated into an SMS message.

Comment: You have to use API from some vendors.They will have sample code in most of languages.Here is sample code of one of vender http://duo.fastalerts.in/examples/FastAlertsClient.java.txt
http://duo.fastalerts.in/fastalerts_http_api_documentation_v1.3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not going to give you step by step instructions, because then I'd be writing your code for you - right?

That said, you can use one of a number of SMS APIs to accomplish what you want. I happen to do some occasional developer evangelism for Nexmo, so I'll use that as an example, but it's the same basic concept for any SMS API.

**Verifying the number**: You make an HTTP request to Nexmo's API to send an SMS to the user containing your verification code. The request parameters contain your API access credentials, as well as the to, from, and text of the message. Here's an [example verification service](https://github.com/Nexmo/Verify) using Nexmo to send the verification messages.

**Sending Bulk Messages**: When a user verifies the subscription, you're going to store that somewhere. When you're ready to send the messages, just loop through that list, and make a HTTP request to the API for each message (every subscriber). Depending on the size of the list, and where you're sending the message, you'll need to ensure your loop checks the response status from the API, and handles and rate issues / watches your balance, etc.

Here's how to [send a message, from Nexmo's docs](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/messaging-sms-api/send-message). Since you're using Java, you'll probably be interested in the [Java client library](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/pre-built-libraries).